# How do I get my Wiki to automatically link dois to their respective websites?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Yet again I must ask this brilliant website for advice, currently, on my Wiki PMIDs are automatically linked provided they're given in the form: PMID #, where # refers to the PMID number. Likewise ISBNs are linked when the ISBN is given before the book's ISBN. I would like the same to occur for dois given in the format: doi:#.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely all about an extension. The question isn’t mentioning if you are using Semantic MediaWiki, are you? If yes, you will have to find ways to know the list of whatever that is (doi:# ???)  and handle this.

Comment: No, I don't even know what Semantic MediaWiki is.

Comment: If you go to the Special:Version page of your MediaWiki installation, you will see all the extensions. Maybe its there, or something there will tell you about "PMID" or "ISBN" auto links. Its clearly not a native MediaWiki feature it has to be an extension and also it has to query something and keep a copy.

Comment: Nope there's no option on that page.